# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values', long_repeat, 11

Tags: python

Dears

Can someone help with below code, I got error which is in title

```
def long_repeat(line):
    count = {}
    for item in line:
        count.setdefault(item, 0)
        count[item] += 1
        result = (max(zip(count.values(), count.keys())))
        for v in result.values():
            print (v)
    return (v)
```

Comment: Why `result.values()`? `result` is enough.

Comment: What is `line` and how do you call the function? What would be the expected result? I'm missing an [mcve]...

Comment: Hi Guys, I need return values from "result" dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are pairs of values unlike lists are pairs auf a key and a value.
Try again without the .values Attribute like this (v2 would be the second value of the tuple):

```
def long_repeat(line):
    count = {}
    for item in line:
        count.setdefault(item, 0)
        count[item] += 1
        result = (max(zip(count.values(), count.keys())))
        for v1,v2 in result:
            print (v2)
    return (v2)
```

To get the char with the most repetitions:

```
def long_repeat(line):
count = {}
for item in line:
    count.setdefault(item, 0)
    count[item] += 1
result = zip(count.values(), count.keys())
return (max(zip(count.values(), count.keys())))
```

Testing:

```
print(long_repeat("hallo hallo"))
```

Would display: (4, 'l')

If you want to extract the values too use:

```
v1, v2 = (long_repeat("sdsffffse"))
```

If you try to print that:

```
print(v1,v2)
```

It returns:
4 f

```
print(v1)
```

Returns: 4

Comment: Hi Fabian, Now error is "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, long_repeat, 11"

Comment: I need return how many times repeated letter in string for example long_repeat("sdsffffse") f - repeted 4 times so answer should 4

Comment: Tested it for your example...it returned: (4, 'f')

Comment: it display (4, 'l') but write answer for me just 4

Comment: then use number,letter = (long_repeat("sdsffffse")) 
and number is gonna be 4

Comment: did that answer your question? Don't forget to mark this answer as correct :)